# Find tie values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, window-functions

I have a table such as the following:

| student | quizId | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 90 |
| B | 1 | 95 |
| A | 2 | 87 |
| B | 2 | 87 |

I want to get this result:

| quizId | highestGrade | isTie |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 95 | 0 |
| 2 | 87 | 1 |

Is there any simple way to do this besides RANK WITH TIES?

Comment: You can do a rank and group by then add a count.  Then in your isTie column do a case where count(*) > 1 then isTie =1

Comment: Are you guaranteed only two values per group?

Comment: @shawnt00 - no, could be multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation to get the number of students for each combination of `quizId` and `score` and `MAX()` window function to get the `highestGrade`.

A `CASE` expression may be used to get the column `isTie`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT quizId,
       MAX(score) OVER (PARTITION BY quizId) AS highestGrade,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isTie
FROM tablename
GROUP BY quizId, score;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8j_xrK7a).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if there is a tie with the max value for each quiz, you may use the max window function and aggregate as the following:

```
with maxScores as
(
  select *,
    max(score) over (partition by quizId) highestGrade
  from table_name 
)
select quizId, highestGrade,
   case 
     when count(*) > 1 then 1
     else 0
   end as isTie
from maxScores
where score = highestGrade
group by quizId, highestGrade
order by quizId
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/b9vgmQbu)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `ROW_NUMBER` and `LEAD` for this. Note that this only requires at most a single sort in the query plan.

```sql
SELECT
  quizId,
  score AS highestGrade,
  IIF(prevScore = score, CAST(1 AS bit), CAST(0 AS bit)) AS isTie
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn       = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY quizId ORDER BY score DESC),
      prevScore = LEAD(score) OVER (PARTITION BY quizId ORDER BY score DESC)
    FROM tablename
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/C9GxLyKK)